# Taking an Integer Array from a Void * Parameter

Tags: c

Given a function that has the parameter void *X, how can I pass as an argument an integer array x and have a local integer variable y within that function set to X?

```
    ...

int x[2];

x[0] = 1;
x[1] = 2;

foo((void*)x);

        ... 
/*foo function:*/

void foo(void *X) {
//I want a local variable y (integer array) to be set to X

}
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering why I need this http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html the linux clone function can only take void arguments that are passed as parameters to the child process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to declare an `int *` pointer and assign the `void *` pointer to it, just as simple as that

```
void foo(void *X) {
    int *x;
    x = X;
    if (x == NULL) /* prevent NULL dereference */
        return;
}
```

and the `f((void *)x);` is not needed, you can just use `f(x);`

Also, depending on your needs you might want to create a struct and pass a pointer to the struct holding the number of items your array can fit, that would be safer, and esiear to maintain.

This is a quote from the C11 draft 1570

> **§ 6.3.2.3 Poitners**
>
> 1. A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: Nor do you need the cast in the function. This is C, after all. `int *x = X;` will suffice.

Comment: @WhozCraig sure, I don't know why i give advice about one cast and use the other one....